# LINQ Select IDs from multiple levels

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'd like to get one list of IDs from all nested entities.

Code:

```cs
// Entities
class Floor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; } = new List<Room>();
}

class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chair> Chairs { get; set; } = new List<Chair>();
}
class Chair
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

// Setup
var floor = new Floor() { Id = 1000 };
var room = new Room() { Id = 100 };
var chair = new Chair() { Id = 10 };

room.Chairs.Add(chair);
floor.Rooms.Add(room);

var floors = new List<Floor>() { floor };

// Select all IDs
var ids = floors.???
```

Expected result:

```
{ 10, 100, 1000 }
```

What I've tried. It selects IDs only from the deepest level, not all of them:

```cs
// Select all IDs
var ids = floors
    .SelectMany(f => f.Rooms)
    .SelectMany(r => r.Chairs)
    .Select(ch => ch.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's pretty important information that you're not actually asking about plain linq-to-objects, but queries that need to be translatable to SQL instead. Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectMany` is what you need together with `Append`:

```
var ids = floors
    .SelectMany(f => f.Rooms
        .SelectMany(r => r.Chairs
            .Select(c => c.Id).Append(r.Id)).Append(f.Id));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code flattens the hierarchy to collection of `Chair` and selects only their ids.

With pure LINQ you can do via nesting `SelectMany` and using `Append`/`Prepend`:

```cs
var ids = floors
    .SelectMany(f => f.Rooms
        .SelectMany(r => r.Chairs
            .Select(ch => ch.Id) // select chairs ids
            .Append(r.Id)) // append "current" room id to it's collection of chair ids
        .Append(f.Id)) // append "current" floor id to it's collection of rooms and chairs ids
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It works. Is there alternative to `.Append` as it's not working for LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @sofigi7386 such handling will be harder to reproduce in SQL. I suggest converting this to unions, something like `floors.Select(f => f.Id).Union(floors.SelectMany(f => f.Rooms).Select(f => f.Id)).Union(...)`

Answer (score 1):

An ugly hack would be to append "fakes" to the child rooms/chairs with the ID of their parent:

```cs
var ids = floors
    .SelectMany(f => f.Rooms.Append(new Room { Id = f.Id }))
    .SelectMany(r => r.Chairs.Append(new Chair { Id = r.Id }))
    .Select(ch => ch.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a recursive helper function like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> CollectIds<T>(T x) => x switch {
    Floor f => f.Rooms.SelectMany(CollectIds).Prepend(f.Id),
    Room r => r.Chairs.SelectMany(CollectIds).Prepend(r.Id),
    Chair c => Enumerable.Repeat(c.Id, 1),
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
};
```

Usage:

```cs
var ids = floors
    .SelectMany(CollectIds)
    .ToList();
```

You could consider extracting this function into a common interface to avoid the awkward type switch and the recursion.